# Generate pdf on the fly with charts

Tags: php, pdf, highcharts, yii2, amcharts

I need to generate PDF report on the fly and somehow insert a image version of a Chart.

As a resume, I'm using Yii2, mpdf extension from Kartik (http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf), and amCharts.

I know both amCharts and HighCharts, have ways to export the graph as images on the fly, but for that I need JavaScript to render, and as far as I know, there isn't a way to render HTML to PDF, and load JavaScript to execute something. MPDF Supports HTML, CSS, etc, but afaik NOT JavaScript.

This was a feature by a client, which gave me a link to a private app (that all I know runs on PHP), that is accomplishing this with HighCharts, I don't mind swapping to HighCharts if there is a way I'm missing..

I need to render my view, into PDF and attach a dynamically generate amCharts as a image in my PDF.

Out-of-the-box ideas are welcome, as this needs to be made, even if it's with some sloppy, lame way.

But I really I'm not seeing how..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any easy way to do this with client side charts, you should use a server side chart generator like this one : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server#java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really did try all kinds of dark magic.
Apparently I really can't do it.

I don't have an exact solution to the question, but I have the best next thing  I think.

What I did, was render a white "% Loading page", after the user asks for the PDF on-the-fly Report.

This intermediate white page, loads the graphics (into the page, hidden), then amCharts JS library exports them into an image, I then transform it into data/base64 and post it back to the server, it takes 2\3 extra seconds longer, and then the user gets his PDF Report.